# MySQL select from table 1 if data exists in table 2

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables. The first one `favorites` contains users favorite tv shows (structure below). The second one `episodes` has a column `permalink` as well as other data about each episode. I want to select everything from `episodes` with `permalink = show_permalink` and `userid = 32`. Could anyone help me with the query?

```
Table: favorites

id |  userid  |   show_permalink 
----------------------------------
1  |  32      |   the-strain 
2  |  5       |   still-the-king 
3  |  32      |   game-of-thrones
```

Episodes table:

[image: episodes table]

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Here is what I tried: ` SELECT * FROM `episodes` WHERE `permalink` in (SELECT `show_permalink` FROM `customcalendar` WHERE `userid` = '32') ORDER BY `air_date_PT` ` However, this only displays one of the two shows (the last one  in order - game of thrones).

Comment: The only relationship between the tables is the `permalink` column.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking me. Is this helping?
 http://i.imgur.com/Bdg5jy2.png http://i.imgur.com/BXj347J.png

Comment: No, the id for the favorites really has no function. I might as well delete it. The only thing to compare them is the `permalink` and `show_permalink`.

Comment: Not gonna be able to help unless you add a few **example rows** from your `episodes` table to your question. Please [edit] the question. Please avoid the use of screenshots.

Comment: @O.Jones check out this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/BXj347J.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both column has same data type then it will work

```
SELECT episodes.* FROM episodes 
INNER JOIN favorites ON(favorites.show_permalink = episodes.permalink) 
where favorites.userid = 32
```

Comment: @Yahya explanation please, because OP simply want to get episodes data where permalink match with show_permalink

Comment: @user3712320 should this be an inner join as per my solution, outer join is only working because of where clause and could cause problems later with all favorites being returned?

Comment: If op want to get data only when both column matched otherwise no result  Then Inner Join should be used, In question it wasn't clear so i used Left Join

Comment: My concern is he said 'I want to select everything from episodes with permalink = show_permalink' - this suggests an inner join first then userid condition.

Comment: @user3712320 I think its better with the inner join, hope so :-)  I have deleted my answer so thread is clear. Eitherway,  the questioner has a working solution.

Comment: Yeah there was a typo but I fixed it. No big deal. :)